# chat div in ajax using css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

Chat div in ajax using css. Am building a chat system using ajax, when the chat text exceeds the length of the screen, the newly text message tends to scroll downward beneath the chat text input form instead of scrolling upward and as a result, newly sent message cannot be been unless you scroll downward. Below is how I built my css. any help will be appreciated

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
       $.ajax({ 
         type: "POST", 
         url:'chatposts.php',
         data:"uname="+uname,
         success:function(data) {
           $('#chatdisplay').html(data); 
    } }) 

      var elem = document.getElementById('comdisplay');
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

    }, 10000); 
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.chatdisplay {
   background-color:#FF00FF; 
   min-width:100px;
   height:auto;
   margin-left:56px; 
   padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
   margin-top:1px; 
   font-size:12px; 
   color:#000;
}
#chatbox {
  display:block; 
  bottom:0;  
  margin-left: 0px; 
  position:fixed; 
  width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chatdisplay" >
    Display chat message...
</div>


<div id="chatbox">
   <form action="" method="post" name="chat_form">
      <input name="chat_comment" class="comment" type="text" id="chat_comment">
      <input name="chatBtn" class="chatBtn" id="chatbtn" type="submit" value="Chat" />
   </form>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
       require('db.php');
       $result = $db->prepare('
       select * from chat where pid=:pid order by cmid');
       $result->execute(array(':pid' => '43'));
       $countcom=$result->rowCount();
       while ($full = $result->fetch()) {
         $cmid=htmlentities($full['cmid'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
         $cname1=htmlentities($full['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
         $comment_pic2=htmlentities($full['user_pic66'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
         $tt=htmlentities($full['c_time'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
         $bb=htmlentities($full['user_name66'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    ?>
    <div id="chatdisplay<?php echo $cmid;?>" class="chatdisplay" >
    <img width="20" height="20" src='http://localhost/sri_chat/db/photo/<?php echo $comment_pic2;?>' /> 
    &nbsp;

   <?php 
     echo $bb;
   ?>: &nbsp;<?php echo $cname1;?>


    </div>

    <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with pure CSS. But you could do it with JavaScript.

### Example:

**HTML:** (*A bit different than yours, but same concept*)

```
<div class="message">
    <p>This was the first message</p>
    <p>Another message</p>
    <p>A third message about something a bit longer</p>    
</div>

<button>New message</button>
```

**JS:** (*I used jQuery in this example*)

```
var button = $('button');
var container = $(".message");

button.on('click', function() {
    container.append('<p> A new message</p>');
    container.scrollTop(container[0].scrollHeight);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/u4u33286/3/

Comment: New message still can't comeup unless i scrolled down. I have edited the post and added all the codes for you to see how the structure looks like, perhaps I still need help thanks

Comment: Most likely because the scroll needs to happen after the ajax event is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way to solve the problem would be to invert how you are putting the messages into the box (newest at top) but if you want them at the bottom.

```
var chatBox = document.getElementById("chatdisplay");
chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
```

Should do it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp
For more info on the Dom property

*Kris beat me to it

Comment: New message still can't comeup unless i scrolled down. I have edited the post and added all the codes for you to see how the structure looks like, perhaps I still need help thanks

Comment: real quick you know that getElementById('comdisplay') should be getElementById('chatdisplay') right?  also the way you are doing that i would just put `$('#chatdisplay').scrollTop = $('#chatdisplay').scrollHeight;` right after you set the html inside your success function